# Stripe invoice item list empty when customer not specified

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve ALL pending invoice items on Stripe across ALL customers using the following request:

```bash
curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoiceitems -u "api_key:" -d pending=true
```

This returns an empty list response:

```json
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/invoiceitems"
}
```

If I specify a customer though:

```bash
curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoiceitems -u "api_key:" -d pending=true -d customer=cus_XXX
```

Then I do get the pending invoice items for only that customer. How can I get pending invoice items for ALL customers?

Comment: When I test using the customer-less pattern you describe I get results across customers, so I suspect something else is going on here. Are you should you aren't using a different account's API key? I would suggest writing to Stripe's support team with specific request ID examples and potentially a short reproduction script: https://support.stripe.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, listing Invoice Items won't give you anything without either `customer` or `invoice` context.

This isn't the only object this logic is relevant for. Payment Methods are another example. You'll get an empty list unless specifying a Customer they would belong to.

Retrieving all Invoice Items irrespective of `customer`or `invoice` isn't possible on Stripe. But being honest I can't think of a use-case it would be useful for - feel free to let me know.